# returning the position of an array

Tags: java, arrays, find

I am trying to create a find method, that will check every entry in my PhoneDirectory, and return the position of the name that matches the name given in the parameter. This is what  currently have:

```
private String find(String name) {
    for (DirectoryEntry x : theDirectory) {
        if (x.getName().equals(name)) {
            return x.getName();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

However I will be calling my find function from within other methods that don't necessarily want the name returned, but instead the number attached to the name, (each DirectoryEntry has a name and a telno).
Any help regarding how to return the position of the array instead of just the matching name, would be much appreciated.

Comment: This not much different than what you have. Just replace the for each loop with a "normal" for loop, and return the index when you found it, otherwise return -1.

Answer (score 3):

you can take a couter to count the postion

```
private int find(String name) {
    int i = 0;
    for (DirectoryEntry x : theDirectory) {
        if (x.getName().equals(name)) {
            return i;
        } 
        i++;
    }

    return -1;  // returning -1 if not found
}
```

or you can use normal for loop instead of foreach

Comment: Thankyou that works great. How would I now return the telno in that array position from another method. The method body currently consists of find(name);

Comment: find(name) will return the position now.

Answer (score 1):

```
private String find(String name) {
    int k=0;
    for (DirectoryEntry x : theDirectory) {
        if (x.getName().equals(name)) {
            k++;
            return x.getName();
        }
    }
//k will give you pos
    return null;
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you supposed to get the value of k from this function?

Comment: @PakkuDon append it with the name with some unique separator and parse it after.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the position in the array, use a regular loop instead of a foreach loop.

```
for (int i=0;i<theDirectory.length;i++) {
DirectoryEntry x = theDirectory[i];
    if (x.getName().equals(name)) {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of your `theDirectory`-field you could use an own counter up to its `length`:

```
private int find(String name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < theDirectory.length(); i++) {
        DirectoryEntry x = theDirectory[i]; //If it is an Array; for Lists use get etc...
        if (x.getName().equals(name)) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to avoid reinventing the wheel and use Guava instead:

```
private int find(String name) {
    return Iterables.indexOf(theDirectory, new Predicate<DirectoryEntry>() {
        public boolean apply(DirectoryEntry de) {
            return de.getName().equals(name);
        }
    });
}
```